# Qt Wrapper class on libWebSockets - not emitting a signal from the callback method

Tags: qt, websocket, qt-signals, libwebsockets

I am writing a WebSocket client application, based on the [example](https://github.com/warmcat/libwebsockets/blob/master/minimal-examples/ws-client/minimal-ws-client-rx/minimal-ws-client.c), where the client application needs to pass the `WebSocket Protocol` while establishing connection with the server. Since QtWebSockets does not support the Websocket protocols, I am writing a C++ wrapper to use [libWebSockets](https://github.com/warmcat/libwebsockets) library and emit 
`connected, disconnected, textReceived` kind of signals similar to QWebSocket.

My client application is able to connect to the server and is receiving the text message from the server, and I have copied minimum example code below, here I am facing an issue that when I emit a signal from the callback function the signal is not actually published and the slot I have connected to this signal never executed. I have verified that the object address passed in the session data is correct (copied the Logs of my program). What am I doing wrong here.

---

**WebSocket.h**

```
class WebSocket : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    WebSocket(QObject *parent = Q_NULLPTR);
    ~WebSocket();

signals:
    void connected();
    void disconnected();
    void textMessageReceived(const QString &message);

private:
    static int callback_dumb_increment(struct lws *wsi, enum lws_callback_reasons reason,
        void *user, void *in, size_t len);

    struct lws_context *context;
    struct lws *client_wsi;
    static const struct lws_protocols protocols[];
};
```

---

**WebSocket.cpp**

```
const struct lws_protocols WebSocket::protocols[] = {
    {
        "dumb_protocol",
        callback_dumb_increment,
        sizeof(per_session_data),
        0,
    },
    { NULL, NULL, 0, 0 }
};

WebSocket::WebSocket(QObject *parent) : QObject(parent)
{
    struct lws_context_creation_info info;
    struct lws_client_connect_info i;
    int n = 0;

    memset(&info, 0, sizeof info); /* otherwise uninitialized garbage */
    info.port = CONTEXT_PORT_NO_LISTEN; /* we do not run any server */
    info.protocols = protocols;

    qDebug() << "[parent] address: " << this;
    info.user = this;

    /*
     * since we know this lws context is only ever going to be used with
     * one client wsis / fds / sockets at a time, let lws know it doesn't
     * have to use the default allocations for fd tables up to ulimit -n.
     * It will just allocate for 1 internal and 1 (+ 1 http2 nwsi) that we
     * will use.
     */
    info.fd_limit_per_thread = 1 + 1 + 1;

    context = lws_create_context(&info);
    if (!context) {
        qDebug() << "lws init failed";
    }

    memset(&i, 0, sizeof i); /* otherwise uninitialized garbage */
    i.context = context;

    i.port = 7070;
    i.address = "localhost";
    i.path = "/";
    i.host = i.address;
    i.origin = i.address;
    i.pwsi = &client_wsi;

    lws_client_connect_via_info(&i);

    while (n >= 0 && client_wsi)
        n = lws_service(context, 0);
}


int WebSocket::callback_dumb_increment( struct lws *wsi, enum lws_callback_reasons reason,
                                        void *user, void *in, size_t len )
{
    /* This will be same for every connected peer */
    void *userdata = lws_context_user(lws_get_context(wsi));
    qDebug() << "userData address: " << userdata;

    QString message = "";

    switch (reason) {

    case LWS_CALLBACK_CLIENT_CONNECTION_ERROR:
        if (in)
            qDebug() << "CLIENT_CONNECTION_ERROR: " << (char *)in;
        else
            qDebug() << "CLIENT_CONNECTION_ERROR: (null)";
        wsi = NULL;
        break;

    case LWS_CALLBACK_CLIENT_ESTABLISHED:
        qDebug() << __func__ << " established";
        emit static_cast<WebSocket*>(userdata)->connected();
        break;

    case LWS_CALLBACK_CLIENT_RECEIVE:
        message = QString::fromUtf8((const char *)in);
        qDebug() << "RX: " << message;
        emit static_cast<WebSocket*>(userdata)->textMessageReceived(message);
        break;

    case LWS_CALLBACK_CLIENT_CLOSED:
        wsi = NULL;
        emit static_cast<WebSocket*>(userdata)->disconnected();
        break;

    default:
        break;

    }

    return lws_callback_http_dummy(wsi, reason, user, in, len);
}
```

---

**SocketClient.h**

```
class SocketClient : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit SocketClient(QObject *parent = Q_NULLPTR);
    ~SocketClient();

public slots:
    void onConnected();
    void onTextMessageReceived(QString message);

private:
    std::shared_ptr<WebSocket> webSock = nullptr;
};
```

---

**SocketClient.cpp**

```
SocketClient::SocketClient(QObject *parent) :QObject(parent)
{
    webSock = std::make_shared<WebSocket>(this);    

    connect(webSock .get(), &WebSocket::connected, this, &SocketClient::onConnected);
    connect(webSock .get(), &WebSocket::textMessageReceived,
        this, &SocketClient::onTextMessageReceived);
}
```

Logs:

```
[parent] address:  WebSocket(0x1b2cae32140)
userData address:  0x1b2cae32140
WebSocket::callback_dumb_increment  established
userData address:  0x1b2cae32140
RX:  "Hello World"
```

Comment: You are attempting to emit signals from within the static method. I don't think it's going to work because in order to emit a Qt signal, you need to do it from inside a non-static method of the sender which should be a `QObject` subclass containing `Q_OBJECT` macro.

Comment: In other words, from `callback_dumb_increment` you need to invoke some non-static method of `WebSocket` which would emit the needed signal.

Comment: I have even tried that, but still it did not work. I have added a non-static method `void WebSocket::emitConnected()
{
 emit connected();
}` and in the callback method I have invoked that medhod as:  `static_cast<WebSocket*>(userdata)->emitConnected();` and still the same issue.